# How do I fake a Firestore Flow<QuerySnapshot> in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to test my app with firestore and I don't know how will I fake the datasource with a Flow to test my repository. I'm trying to follow the pattern from google codelabs but I only convert toObject in the composable. How can I write the repository test?

below is my FirestoreDatasource and my Repository and the FakeDatasource I am trying to write

```
@Singleton
class FirestoreDatasourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore
) : FirestoreDatasource {

    override suspend fun addUser(user: UserModel) {
        firestore.collection(USERS)
            .document(user.id)
            .set(user, SetOptions.merge())
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun getAllUsers(userId: String) = callbackFlow {
        val collection = firestore.collection(USERS).whereNotEqualTo("id", userId)

        val snapshotListener = collection.addSnapshotListener() { snapshot, e ->
            this.trySend(snapshot).isSuccess
        }

        awaitClose {
            snapshotListener.remove()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Singleton
class FirestoreRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firestoreClass: FirestoreDatasourceImpl
) : FirestoreRepository{

    override suspend fun addUser(user: UserModel){
        firestoreClass.addUser(user)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun getAllUsers(userId: String) : Flow<QuerySnapshot?> {
         return firestoreClass.getAllUsers(userId)
    }
}
```

```
internal class FakeFirestoreDatasourceImplTest constructor(
    private var userList: MutableList<UserModel>? = mutableListOf()
) : FirestoreDatasource{


    override suspend fun addUser(user: UserModel) {
        userList?.add(user)
    }

    override fun getAllUsers(userId: String): Flow<QuerySnapshot?> {

    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Your addUser suspend fun doesn't actually suspend.  It needs to use the Task returned by set() in order to suspend properly.  There is a library that can help you with that.  2.  I suggest using a StateFlow as a better model for how Firestore snapshot listeners work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know you are not an Android person but Firebase, but in case you have any samples for writing test for `Firestore` queries for Android, can you please provide? :)

Comment: @DougStevenson how can I change my callbackFlow to a StateFlow in my firestoreClass attaching the snapshotListener? I could only find how to do it in the viewModel

Comment: You can refer to [this document](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test) to know more about StateFlow. Are you referring to [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-test-doubles#0)? If yes, then please provide the error message you are getting. If this is not the codelab you are referring to, then please provide the reference and any error message you are getting with some minimum code so that it will be easy to reproduce the issue.